# newcommand returns math mode error

Tags: math-mode, macros

I don't see why the custom (temperature) command `\newcommand{\deg}{$^\circ$F}` returns a `"missing $ inserted"` error when writing something like `350\deg` in text mode.  More confusingly, it compiles if I use `\renewcommand`, suggesting the command name `\deg` has already been used. But the same error is returned no matter the command name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit off-topic, however:

- Fahrenheit are not standard unit, instead it is correct to use Celsius degrees.
- If you for some reason persist to use it, than is sensible to define them as part od `siunitx` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}    % <---
\DeclareSIUnit{\fahrenheit}{^\circ\mkern-1mu\mathrm{F}} % <---

\begin{document}

proposed solution: \qty{350}{\fahrenheit};

by your solution: 350$^\circ$F

\end{document}
```

since its use gives typographical more correct form than it would be with your intended definition:

[image]

Comment: If the OP wants to use the *de facto* standard temperature unit in a country of more than 300 million people, I think they should be allowed to do that. Not everything we write with TeX is necessarily scientific publications.

Comment: @Gaussler, in answer I wrote "if for some reason" . This you can read as *de-facto standard*. Also you can see, that answer provide a solution how they can nice write temperatures in any text where desired. Or they are also obligated to have bad typography :-)?

Comment: My remark was simply about the first sentence. And yes, your solution is good, even though I don’t understand why `\fahrenheit` is not predefined by `siunitx`. Perhaps @JosephWright can tell us why?

Comment: @Gaussler, somewhere  as comment  he wrote: ".... because in the package are considered only units which are not listed as deprecated in the  BIPM (Bureau International des Poids et Mesures)" (cited as remembered).

Comment: The choice of Fahrenheit is preferable within the scope of my local application, but your general point about standard units is well taken.  I also appreciate the typographical pointer.

Answer (score 3):

With `\newcommand`, I get

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \deg already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

which I'm assuming you ignored when running with that version of the command. `\deg` is one of the text operator symbols provided by LaTeX. It's used in graph theory to say things like

> ∑<sub>*v* ∈ *V*</sub> deg(*v*) = 2|*E*|

When you ran past the error, `\deg` was not redefined but instead you got the original math command and thus the error.

When I changed to `\renewcommand` I didn't get the error.

Comment: I totally overlooked that LaTeX error, like 10 times!  That makes my question worthless to anyone else.  Should this post be flagged for deletion?  In any case, thanks for your help.

Comment: It's a common error, don't worry. Nevertheless, I suggest that you don't redefine `\deg` command but use another name for it, to avoid further issues if you have to use the *deg* symbol.

Comment: @steven_nevets In order to avoid problems like this, I normally use a prefix that makes it unlikely that the name is already used, e. g. `my_`. This is not only true for LaTeX. In addition, this also makes it easier for me when I read my own code a year later then I know that the command is/was defined by me and not available "out of the box" (I have a bad memory).

Comment: I mean `myCommand` since `_` is not allowed in LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

You can use also `gensymb` package or `siunitx` as this example without to declare a predefinite command named `\deg`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{gensymb}

\begin{document}
Your angle is \ang{350} (siunitx package) or 350{\degree} (gensymb package).
\end{document}
```

[image]

The MWE work also in math-mode: `$\ang{350}$, $350{\degree}$`.